# Jquery-UI diagloge scrolls to top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery-ui and I am trying to have it so when clicking the "click me" link it opens the modal. However, since the link is directed to "#" it also scrolls to the top of the page. How can I prevent it doing that? I think it is something to do with `e.preventdefault`

```
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
});

$( "#btn_sec2" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

And the button to open it:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" id="btn_sec2">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**:

```
$( "#btn_sec2" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```